# How to convert radius map to km or meter?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Converting radius ratio to km or meter.

What if I put radius=500? What will be the equivalency of radius 500 to kilometer or meter?

What is 1 radius to km?

```
   StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=10000");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + "art_gallery");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyCx8-ZK6m5FTgEoTaSRaUuALV-5Vnz1Co4");
        Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
        return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radius parameter is in meters. So you should convert in meter, then pass it in below url.

```
StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=10000");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + "art_gallery");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyCx8-ZK6m5FTgEoTaSRaUuALV-5Vnz1Co4");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
```